# Google Sheets - fix script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

There is a script respected Hyde - [link](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/149743347?hl=en&msgid=149890712). This script copies protected sheets along with the protection. It has three different use cases. How do I leave out the part of the script that does **"copy a sheet to another spreadsheet, using the same sheet name, and put it at the first position in the tab bar"**.

---

```
/**
* Copies a sheet, retaining protections.
* 
* The copy can be created within the same spreadsheet file as the original,
* or in another spreadsheet file.
*
* If a sheet by the name optNewSheetName already exists in the spreadsheet,
* the new sheet is named 'Copy of Template' or similar.
*
* Usage:
 
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheetToCopy = ss.getSheetByName('Template');
  let newSheet;
 
  // duplicate a template sheet, and put it at the last position in the tab bar
  const newSheetName = 'Data ' + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  newSheet = copySheetWithProtections_(sheetToCopy, newSheetName);
 
  // copy a sheet to another spreadsheet, using the same sheet name, and put it at the first position in the tab bar
  const targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('123abc...cba321');
  newSheet = copySheetWithProtections_(sheetToCopy, undefined, 0, targetSpreadsheet);
 
  // copy sheets '1', '2' and '3' to another spreadsheet, and put them at the end of the tab bar
  const sheetsToCopy = ['1', '2', '3',];
  const newSheets = [];
  sheetsToCopy.forEach(sheetName => {
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    newSheets.push(copySheetWithProtections_(sheet, sheetName, undefined, targetSpreadsheet));
  });
  console.log(`Copied ${newSheets.length} sheets to '${targetSpreadsheet.getName()}'.`);
 
* @param {Sheet} sheet The sheet to copy.
* @param {String} optNewSheetName Optional. Defaults to the name of the source sheet.
* @param {Number} optSheetIndex Optional. The zero-indexed position of the new sheet in the tab bar. Defaults to the last position.
* @param {String} optTargetSpreadsheet Optional. The target spreadsheet. Defaults to the current spreadsheet.
* @return {Sheet} The new copy of sheet.
*/
function copySheetWithProtections_(sheet, optNewSheetName, optSheetIndex, optTargetSpreadsheet) {
  // version 1.2, written by --Hyde, 16 February 2022
  //  - add optTargetSpreadsheet
  //  - see https://support.google.com/docs/thread/147940588
  // version 1.1, written by --Hyde, 8 February 2022
  //  - see https://support.google.com/docs/thread/149743347?msgid=149890712
  //  - see https://support.google.com/docs/thread/144274437
  //  - see https://support.google.com/docs/thread/126744993
 
  const ss = sheet.getParent();
  const newSheetName = optNewSheetName || sheet.getName();
  const targetSs = optTargetSpreadsheet || ss;
  const sheetIndex = optSheetIndex ?? targetSs.getNumSheets() + 1;
  const me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  if (!me.getEmail()) {
    throw new Error('Cannot retrieve identity of the effective user.');
  }
  const newSheet = sheet.copyTo(targetSs);
  newSheet.activate();
  targetSs.moveActiveSheet(sheetIndex);
  try {
    newSheet.setName(newSheetName);
  } catch (error) {
    ; // the sheet name is already taken, retain the default 'Copy of...' name
  }
  const sheetProt = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0];
  if (sheetProt) {
    const newSheetProt = newSheet
      .protect()
      .setDescription(sheetProt.getDescription())
      .setWarningOnly(sheetProt.isWarningOnly());
    if (!sheetProt.isWarningOnly()) {
      newSheetProt
        .addEditor(me)
        .removeEditors(newSheetProt.getEditors().filter(user => user.getEmail() !== me))
        .addEditors(sheetProt.getEditors());
      try {
        newSheetProt.setDomainEdit(sheetProt.canDomainEdit());
      } catch (error) {
        ; // we are not in a Google Workspace domain
      }
    }
    const unprotectedRanges = sheetProt.getUnprotectedRanges()
      .map(range => newSheet.getRange(range.getA1Notation()));
    newSheetProt.setUnprotectedRanges(unprotectedRanges);
  } else {
    sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE)
      .forEach(rangeProt => {
        const rangeA1 = rangeProt.getRange().getA1Notation();
        const newRangeProt = newSheet.getRange(rangeA1)
          .protect()
          .setDescription(rangeProt.getDescription())
          .setWarningOnly(rangeProt.isWarningOnly());
        if (!rangeProt.isWarningOnly()) {
          newRangeProt
            .addEditor(me)
            .removeEditors(newRangeProt.getEditors().filter(user => user.getEmail() !== me))
            .addEditors(rangeProt.getEditors());
          try {
            newRangeProt.setDomainEdit(rangeProt.canDomainEdit());
          } catch (error) {
            ; // we are not in a Google Workspace domain
          }
        }
      });
  }
  return newSheet;
}
```

How can I get a script out of this that does **"copy a sheet to another spreadsheet, using the same sheet name, and put it at the first position in the tab bar"**?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. This show what you have tried to adapt the script to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get a script out of this that does "copy a sheet to another spreadsheet, using the same sheet name, and put it at the first position in the tab bar"?

Follow the usage example in the [JSDoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSDoc), like this:

```js
function copyASheetToAnotherSpreadsheetUsingTheSameSheetNameAndPutItAtTheFirstPositionInTheTabBar() {
  const sheetToCopy = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Template');
  const targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('123abc...cba321');
  const newSheet = copySheetWithProtections_(sheetToCopy, undefined, 0, targetSpreadsheet);
  console.log(`Copied sheet '${newSheet.getName()}' to spreadsheet '${targetSpreadsheet.getName()}'.`);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Added your code to the script. Changed to real spreadSheetID. Error while executing - 

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getParent')
copySheetWithProtections_ @ copy_to_another_file.gs:56
copyASheetToAnotherSpreadsheetUsingTheSameSheetNameAndPutItAtTheFirstPositionInTheTabBar @ copy_to_another_file.gs:43

I am a beginner user of Google Sheets. Scripts are hard for me so far. Could you write the entire script code? Maybe there are obvious things for you. But for me it is still very difficult.

Comment: The error indicates that there is no sheet by the name you used in the `const sheetToCopy` line. To learn scripting, see [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The script in the answer to my question works great.